# How to display the embed video url in Html.FromHTML

Tags: android, html, json, iframe, textview

I want to display the embed URL in android textview using Html.FromHTML().

I'm getting this JSON String

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span data-sheets-value=\"{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;This video is about hip hop dance done by Amit. He moved his leg from one of the A R Rahman album which Humma Humma song. The steps are too awesome which made you to shake your legs. Watch this to start shake your legs.&quot;}\" data-sheets-userformat=\"{&quot;2&quot;:7043,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:16777215},&quot;10&quot;:0,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;14&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:3355443},&quot;15&quot;:&quot;\\&quot;Arial\\&quot;,\\&quot;sans-serif\\&quot;&quot;}\">This video is about hip hop dance done by Amit. He moved his leg from one of the A R Rahman album which Humma Humma song. The steps are too awesome which made you to shake your legs. Watch this to start shake your legs.</span></p>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span data-sheets-value=\"{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;This video is about hip hop dance done by Amit. He moved his leg from one of the A R Rahman album which Humma Humma song. The steps are too awesome which made you to shake your legs. Watch this to start shake your legs.&quot;}\" data-sheets-userformat=\"{&quot;2&quot;:7043,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:16777215},&quot;10&quot;:0,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;14&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:3355443},&quot;15&quot;:&quot;\\&quot;Arial\\&quot;,\\&quot;sans-serif\\&quot;&quot;}\">
<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/mhIDO6YMx80\" width=\"560\" height=\"314\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></span></p>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>"
```

I'm displaying this in `TextView` using  Html.FromHTML(). In this i know `<iframe src>` tag will not support in android  Html.FromHTML(). Instead of this how can i display the video. In JSON HTML String it will image & text & Video and all.

Please any one have idea, share it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to display the embed URL in android textview using
>   Html.FromHTML().

you can't. `Html.FromHtml()` doesn't parse/handle `iframe`

> Instead of this how can i display the video

you have to use a `WebView`, or you can use the `YouTube sdk` with all its limitations

Comment: I dont want to use webview. It didnt looks nice.

Comment: then the only advice that I can give you is to use the YouTube sdk with all its limitations.

Comment: i can do with Youtube sdk. But in my scenario, that Html content will multiple things images text herflinks videos. So i cant take the url sperately and load it in sdk. Basically from website editor user will write the description. So that content will come.

Comment: AtLast i used webview and played with `websettings` for style. Thanks